# SuperUser RSS feed and Android 2.2 "news" app (RSS reader).

Tags: discussion, android, rss

I can read https://superuser.com/feeds in Thunderbird but Android 2.2's "News" App says "Add channel error","This URL is not correct".

1) Is there some documentation about the URL for RSS on SuperUser (or generic StackExchange) - I understand there are URL parameters that can be used to specify tags and maybe other features?

2) Does Android's "News" app not understand Atom?

Edit: The HTC user manual for this phone has a section saying

> ## Reading news feeds
>
> Use News to subscribe to news feeds to keep up with the latest buzz on the Internet. News
>   monitors RSS feeds from your favorite news sites, blogs and more, and downloads the most
>   current updates.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Subscribing to a news channel by entering a URL
>
> 1. Press HOME, and then tap > News.
> 2. On the Subscriptions tab, tap Add feeds > Add from URL.
> 3. Enter the complete URL for the RSS feed, and then tap Done.

Comment: The Android News widget to my knowledge makes use of Google News results, not RSS/Atom

Comment: @Sathya: HTC's user manual mentions RSS - see edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I conclude that Android 2.2's "News" app does not understand Atom 1.0

Answer (score 1):

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsuperuser.com%2Ffeeds

> #### Congratulations!
>
> This is a valid Atom 1.0 feed.